# WebView Page don't load url in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, forms, url, xamarin, web

I have a problem with the webview page in xamarin forms. In practice, when I click a button step to the page "WebViewPage" the URL to open. This procedure I did it with many url, but with this url in particular it does not work. In windows it works while on android it comes out a white screen that does not load. Can you tell me why?

```
 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Docenti(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                   var url = new UrlWebViewSource
                    {
                        Url = "https://www.docenti.unina.it"
                    };
                    this.Navigation.PushAsync(new WebView_Page(url));
       }
```

Comment: I've Answered the question below which is the way I used to do so.Still sometimes  it may happen like this  when your intenet connection is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**I m using bundle get the string vale previous activity and pass string in web view**

```
 Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent2.getExtras();
    String link = bundle.getString("Agreement_URL");
    String file_type=bundle.getString("file_type");
    if(file_type.equals("PDF"))
    {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+link);
        setContentView(webView);
    }
    else
    {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(link);
    }
```

**Create a global string and pass the url like this**

Answer (score 0):

I used Xamarin Essentials Nuget which is available for cross platform and did as below

```
public class ClassName
{
//Constructor
public Classname()
{
 Doit();
}

 private async void Doit()
        {
            await OpenBrowser("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }
        public async Task OpenBrowser(string uri)
        {
            await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchType.SystemPreferred);
        }
}
```